# Como exibir número de registros por categoria em PHP e MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela de imóveis em MySql divididos em 6 categorias.
Quero fazer uma consulta que retorne o número de registros para cada categoria.
A única forma que conheço até agora é fazer uma consulta para cada categoria, mas acho que isso exige muito do servidor.
É possível fazer uma única consulta e depois achar uma forma de mostras os resultados separados por categoria?
Ah, como são apenas 6 categorias fixas, não criei outra tabela só de categorias, dispensando o uso de join.

Comment: SELECT
categoria , COUNT(categoria) AS totalCount
FROM
nome_tabela
GROUP
BY categoria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse simples `SELECT` utiliza o `GROUP BY categoria` para agrupar todos os registros com o conteúdo de campo `categoria` iguais. Nas colunas que trazemos tem a própria `categoria` e `COUNT(categoria) qtde` que tem como função contar todas as linhas agrupadas:

```
SELECT categoria, COUNT(categoria) qtde FROM imoveis
GROUP BY categoria;
```

Comment: Nossa, tão simples. Valeu pela força.